# What makes some EXIF tags non-writable?

Tags: exif, id3, exiftool

Certain EXIF tags, for example many of the QuickTime tags listed [here](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/QuickTime.html), are non-writable by common EXIF editors.

[This list](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/index.html) of writable vs. non-writable is maintained by Phil Harvey's `exiftool`, but I have found similar results attempting to edit the same tags with other tools such as MetaClean. My edits to these tags do not persist and the original values return when I reload the file.

Why is that? What about a certain tag makes it uneditable, and is there any manual way to override this?

Comment: Such tools do so to prevent unintended consequences.  For example changing the tags of an ISO image would render the image useless.  There is nothing preventing anyone from writing an EXIF tool that removes or alters tags.

Comment: I've accepted a helpful answer below, and if helpful, here's how I met my specific need (scrubbing some personally identifiable iTunes-related `QuickTime` tags): open the audio files in Sublime Text, search for the HEX-encoded values I knew from `exiftool` (note you'll need to insert spaces every 4 HEX characters), then overwrite with `0`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the tags you linked are not EXIF tags, they are Quicktime tags.  EXIF is just a common, but narrow subset of all types Metadata.  Sorry for being a pedantic ass about it.

In the case of exiftool and especially video files, the standards and formats for such tags is, as Phil Harvey (exiftool author) has put it, a complete mess.  There are apparently a lot of differences in how various programs and cameras implement such metadata.  Phil doesn't feel he has time to troubleshoot all the various differences and edge cases.  To give an example, he recently started adding read support for gps tracks in video files.  This ended up ballooning to having to support over 20 different variations of geotracks.  And that's just for reading.

Followup:  As of exiftool ver 11.39, [a number](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/QuickTime.html#Keys) of the more useful tags have been made writable.  Exiftool now lists them under the group `ItemList` instead of `Quicktime`, though they are still part of the Quicktime group.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful, and you're right: I had thought EXIF was an umbrella term for most types of metadata, but now I understand it is a distinct subset.

Comment: Writing metadata at all mostly means to reconstruct the whole file, which can be quite painful even if you managed to successfully parse existing files metadata formats. And most ExifTool users wouldn't understand that patching one metadata value (same amount of bytes remain) would always work.